# Dygraph - how can we update chart by sending 1 set of data point, rather than the entire data series

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

I would like to update the live data by sending 1 set of data point rather than sending whole data series array and old value should get auto deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done starting from sample of the Gallery [Dynamic Update](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update)

Calling [updateOptions](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#updateOptions) after updating the data series.

Here a snipnet showing how to append a new data and delete the oldest one :

```js
var data = [];
var t = new Date();
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    var x = new Date(t.getTime() - i * 1000);
    data.push([x, Math.random()]);
}

var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), data, {height:200});

window.setInterval(function() {
        var x = new Date(); 
        var y = Math.random();
        data.shift();
        data.push([x, y]);
        g.updateOptions( { 'file': data } );
      }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<div id="graph" />
```